# navbar hovering with multiple lists

Tags: html, css

Q: How do I get the `display:none;` lists to `display:block;` when hovering over the button or list item that has a sub menu?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tC2s/1/)

CSS of lists:

```
.nav-menu-list {
  font-family:'Code Source Pro';
  list-style-type:none;
  color:white;
  background:#242424;
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute;
  font-size:1rem;
  width:110px;
  top:40px;
  right:0;
  z-index:50;
  display:none;
}

.nav-menu-list .nav-sub-menu-1 {
  background:#242424;
  top:0;
  position:absolute;
  width:110px;
  right:111px;
  display:none;  
}
```

what i've tried:

```
.nav-menu-btn:hover .nav-menu-list {
  display:block;
}
```

and

```
.nav-menu-btn:hover > .nav-menu-list {
      display:block;
}
```

and

```
.nav-menu-btn:hover .nav-menu-list {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

I feel like I"m missing something fundamental.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tC2s/2/)

You need to use:

```
.nav-menu:hover .nav-menu-list{
    display:block;
}
.nav-menu-list li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Wow, way too fast. Almost perfect but I can get the rest! <3 I'll accept in 10.